# Integration of $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{6} \cos^{-3}2x \sin2x \,\ dx $?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I tried substituting $x=\frac{\cos t}{2}$

but I didn't got anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:** Rewrite the integrand as
$$\cos^{-3}(2x)\sin(2x)=\tan(2x)\sec^2(2x)$$

Comment: wait, is it cos inverse cube x or $\frac{1}{\sec^3 x}$?

Comment: Do you mean the integrand is $\arccos^3 2x \,\sin 2x$?

Comment: It should be $\sec^3x$, otherwise it would have said $(\cos^{-1}x)^3$

Comment: @Bernard Yeah I meant that.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Ohh, ok. It's the first time I've encountered it, so I got confused.Thanks.

Comment: You see why the handheld calculator notation $\cos{-1}$ is confusional. Better use the mathematical notation `arccos, arcsin, arctan`.

Comment: @Bernard I'll eep that in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For $$\int\cos^m(2x)\sin^{2n+1}(2x)\ dx,$$

choose $\cos(2x)=y$